# Backspin in outer space i.e. in a liquid with no viscosity: not changing direction?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, space

No viscosity means no friction between neighbouring particles. I think outer space is such a place. So a golfball or a tennis ball traveling in space with a large spinning such as [backspin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspin) would not experience the [Magnus effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect) where the ball changes its direction due to spinning.

> **Is this correct? So a ball in outer space would not experience Magnus effect due to a large spinning? So is playing tennis in outer space a very directional game without spins and curvatures?**

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you throw a ball in a vacuum its spin will not affect its trajectory. This isn't because there's a liquid with no viscosity, it's because there isn't anything at all!